# 'User' in 'User-defined classes'

Tags: objective-c

I'm sorry to ask a general question like this but as a newbie I'm hoping it will be passed as such.

I'm a beginner learning objective-c and object-oriented style of programming and I keep coming across the term 'user-defined classes' in learning materials. Forgive me but can anyone explain who or what is meant exactly by 'user' and 'user-defined'?

Comment: You are the user of system frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the classes which is created by user **(developer or you)** is User-defined classes. For example you create one class with "test.m", then "test.m" is user defined class.

NSString, NSNumber, NSMutableArray are not user defined classes because it is provided by system.

Comment: ok, so 'user' doesn't refer to objects or instances of the class?

Comment: No,'user' doesn't refer to objects or instances of the class